# With Ruby and RSpec is there a way with rubocop to disallow constants being declared in the global scope?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec3

I am working on setting up `rubocop` on a test suite I've taken over. The test suite contains a `lib/constants.rb` config that is made available to the test suite, and all tests are all found in a `spec/*` folder. I am setting up `rubocop` so that it **only** runs against the test specs (`spec/*`), and ignores the `lib` folder.

I have set up `RSpec/LeakyConstantDeclaration` with `rubocop` to ensure nobody is potentially re-assigning any of the global constants. This cop rule **works** for any specs written like this, and `rubocop` will correctly flag `RSpec/LeakyConstantDeclaration` on this file:

```
# spec/some_test_spec.rb
describe 'some test' do
  SOME_CONSTANT = { 'blah' => 'blah' }

  # SOME_CONSTANT used somewhere in here
  it 'tests something' do
     ...
  end
end
```

However, I've recently found some more tests that are also doing this (EEK!):

```
# spec/some_other_test_spec.rb
SOME_CONSTANT = { 'blah' => 'blah' }

describe 'some other test' do
  # SOME_CONSTANT used somewhere in here
  it 'tests something else' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Some devs have started declaring their own constants explicitly in the global scope, and this could also potentially re-assign a constant created in the `lib/constants.rb`.

Since I'm running `rubocop` only against the test folder of `spec/*` is there any way to write a `rubocop` convention rule that **disallows constants**, and recommends using `let` or a `local` variable instead?

I'm thinking I may have to write a custom Cop to do this, but wondering if there is a known existing way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have to write your custom cop, declaring constants locally can be useful in general so I don't think this would be upstreamed (or maybe to https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rspec)